# Error 1064 on Mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

I'm writing a trigger in MySQL to take log of table updates. The log table is called individuo_storico and the target table is called individuo. When individuo is updated, I want to check if IDQualifica and IDLivello are changed, if yes a record in individuo_storico is inserted.

I write down this code but I get a #1064 error, where's the syntax error?

```
use ore;
create trigger individuo_update after update on individuo
for each row
begin
    if ( NEW.IDLivello <> OLD.IDLivello or NEW.IDQualifica <> OLD.IDQualifica) then
        insert into individuo_storico(IDIndividuo, IDQualifica, IDLivello) 
        values (NEW.IDIndividuo, NEW.IDQualifica, NEW.IDLivello);
    end if;
end;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: You are missing the delimiter, at the beginning add `delimiter //` and then the last line `end;` should be `end;// delimiter ;`

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan 
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3

first answer is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please wrap your trigger creation with the monikers necessary so the db engine does not choke on it. So three areas:

```
1) line 1
2) right after the end; 
3) and then a reset to a default delimiter.
```

Same concept is typical with stored proc creations.

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger individuo_update after update on individuo
for each row
begin
    if ( NEW.IDLivello <> OLD.IDLivello or NEW.IDQualifica <> OLD.IDQualifica) then
        insert into individuo_storico(IDIndividuo, IDQualifica, IDLivello) 
        values (NEW.IDIndividuo, NEW.IDQualifica, NEW.IDLivello);
    end if;
end;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am not a fan of commenting my code-only answers but even I would explain such an answer. Could you add something please?